queryClient.fetchQuery fails to fetch data inside useEffect
Next.js v14 (Pages Router)
I've been working on sending the dataLayer consists of fetched data from API to Google Tag Manager (GTM).
As the dataLayer needs the fetched data, I'm using two useEffect, the one is for the initial page load and the other is for every router change.
export const useGtmScript = ({ ipAddress }: Props) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { events } = useRouter();

  const dataLayerHandler = async () => {
    return await queryClient
      .fetchQuery({
        queryKey,
        queryFn
      })
      .then((d) => sendDataLayer(d))
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  // initial page load
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await dataLayerHandler();
    })();
  }, []);

  // every route change after initial page load
  useEffect(() => {
    events.on('routeChangeComplete', dataLayerHandler);
    return () => {
      events.off('routeChangeComplete', dataLayerHandler);
    };
  }, []);
};

With this custom hook, when I visit the page, it throws the error saying TypeError: Failed to fetch.
// console-logged error 
error TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.eval [as json] (index.js:21:31)
    at Object.get ($api.ts:540:133)
    at Object.queryFn (queries.ts:12:10)

My assumption is that using two useEffect with same dependancy is might be causing this error, but I have no idea about the exact cause and how to fix it.
What I tried is to use useRef to prevent the useEffect call twice like so:
const onceCalled = useRef(false);

...

  // initial page load
  useEffect(() => {
    if (onceCalled.current !== true) {
      onceCalled.current = true;
      return;
    }
    (async () => {
      await dataLayerHandler();
    })();
  }, []);


With this, error did not occur but the dataLayerHandler was also not called even once on initial page load.
Have anyone envountered similar error before? If you have, I'd appreciate it if you could help me out. Thank you.

Hello,
You can just use useQuery instead of the useEffect.
const {data: dataLayer, isLoading} = useQuery({queryKey, queryFn})
